# Rest Query on the Patient Resource for Finding BOTH/ALL Given Name(s)

Tags: hl7-fhir

How do I search for a person with BOTH given names I provide?

I have the following 2 patients who are "close".  Everything (in the Human Name area) is the same except one of the GivenNames are the same.
Note "Apple" vs "Banana".

```
{
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    "id": "269caf66-0ccc-43e7-b9a5-f16f84db0149",
    "meta": {
        "lastUpdated": "2019-11-20T19:30:26.858917+00:00"
    },
    "type": "searchset",
    "link": [
        {
            "relation": "self",
            "url": "https://localhost:44348/Patient?given=Jingerheimer"
        }
    ],
    "entry": [
        {
            "fullUrl": "https://localhost:44348/Patient/504f6bd3-e9b4-4846-8948-97bf09c70722",
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Patient",
                "id": "504f6bd3-e9b4-4846-8948-97bf09c70722",
                "meta": {
                    "versionId": "1",
                    "lastUpdated": "2019-11-20T19:26:11.005+00:00"
                },
                "identifier": [
                    {
                        "system": "ssn",
                        "value": "111-11-1111"
                    },
                    {
                        "system": "uuid",
                        "value": "da55d068e0784b359fa97498a11543c5"
                    }
                ],
                "name": [
                    {
                        "family": "Smith",
                        "given": [
                            "John",
                            "Apple",
                            "Jingerheimer"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "search": {
                "mode": "match"
            }
        },
        {
            "fullUrl": "https://localhost:44348/Patient/10054ce9-6141-4eca-bc5b-0978f8c8afcb",
            "resource": {
                "resourceType": "Patient",
                "id": "10054ce9-6141-4eca-bc5b-0978f8c8afcb",
                "meta": {
                    "versionId": "1",
                    "lastUpdated": "2019-11-20T19:26:48.962+00:00"
                },
                "identifier": [
                    {
                        "system": "ssn",
                        "value": "222-22-2222"
                    },
                    {
                        "system": "uuid",
                        "value": "52d09f9436d44591816fd229dd139523"
                    }
                ],
                "name": [
                    {
                        "family": "Smith",
                        "given": [
                            "John",
                            "Banana",
                            "Jingerheimer"
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "search": {
                "mode": "match"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

One has GivenNames that include "Apple".  The other includes GivenNames that include "Banana".

This search works fine:

https://localhost:44348/Patient/?given=Jingerheimer

What I have tried is:

https://localhost:44348/Patient/?given=Jingerheimer&given=Apple

but that gives me no results.

Note, omitting "given=Jingerheimer" is not an option....that filters a bunch of others.

I'm trying to get

"Has BOTH of the given names I provide"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is correct, so I think the server does not handle the search correctly. Can you check the self link for your second search to see if it reflects the search you performed? Does the result Bundle have an OperationOutcome detailing something went wrong? If all that seems okay, you'll need to check your server's code.

Comment: {
    "resourceType": "Bundle",
    "id": "c8248791-d251-4e73-a6f1-4234d1e08a22",
    "meta": {
        "lastUpdated": "2019-11-20T21:31:48.1417161+00:00"
    },
    "type": "searchset",
    "link": [
        {
            "relation": "self",
            "url": "https://localhost:44348/Patient?given=Jingerheimer&given=MN694097473"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: The generated sql on the server is not dealing with the double-parameters correctly.  I should be using Vonk instead!

Comment: Alternative syntax for this search is https://localhost:44348/Patient/?given=Jingerheimer,Apple
e.g. see this test server example https://vonk.fire.ly/Patient?given=koos,Harold

Comment: No, that's not alternative syntax for what was asked. Your search is an OR type search, resulting in all Patients that have either the name Jingerheimer or Apple (or both). The client still has to filter the results then.